# Tkinter, canvas, create_text and zooming

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, tcl

Is it normal that Tkinter's Canvas' `create_text` 's font size doesn't change when I change the Canvas' scale with `canvas.scale` ?

I thought that, as it is a high level GUI management system, I wouldn't have to resize manually the text done with `create_text` after a zooming. Isn't this strange, or am I wrong ?

Comment: i have no expertise in that very field, but changing scale is a 'low-level' operation if you're using a framework. Check that the framework does not allow you to modify it, if not request for that feature and/or implement it *a minima* by overloading the methods you use. (it might be too 'expensive' to modify properly the whole framework).

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, even if not entirely what you want. The `scale` method just changes the coordinate lists, but `text` items only have one of those so they just get (optionally) translated.

This also applies to `image` and `bitmap` items. And features of other items like the line width; they're not scaled.