# Zoom In and Out in Text widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a clone of Notepad but stuck in zoom in and zoom out functionality. I was able to make a zoom in and out functionality by changing the text size each time user presses the zoom in and out option but I think it is not the real implementation because I think it is not actually zooming in or zooming out.

With lots of searching I came to know that **Canvas** have **scale** method which can be used to implement the zoom-in functionality and I am able make functionality to zoom in and out of the text widget but it does not affect the text sizes. And [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689760/tkinter-canvas-create-text-and-zooming) the **scale** method in **Canvas** only changes the coordinates of the widgets.

**What have I done so far?**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
font = ('Courier', 10)


def zoom(zoom_scale):
    global font

    font = (font[0],) + (font[1] + 1,)
    text.config(font=font)


canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
zoom_scale = tk.Scale(root, orient='vertical', from_=1, to=500)
zoom_scale.config(command=lambda args: zoom(zoom_scale))

zoom_scale.set(10)

text = tk.Text(frame, font=font)
text.grid(row=0, column=0)

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)
# make sure everything is displayed before configuring the scroll region
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
canvas.pack(fill='both', side='left', expand=True)
zoom_scale.pack(fill='y', side='right')
root.mainloop()
```

**In Notepad, the text size does not increase. I think the text-widget is zooming keeping the text-size same. So how can I make a functionality to zoom in and out of the **TEXT** like NOTEPAD?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaling the canvas will not cause embedded widgets to grow or shrink. The only way to implement zoom is to change the size of the font in the text widget.

The following code is a modified version of your code. The things to notice are:

- the code uses a `Font` object for the font
- the scale doesn't use `lambda`; instead it directly calls `zoom`
- `zoom` will configure the size of the font object, which causes the text widget to zoom
- the canvas and frame inside the canvas have been removed.
- the root widget has been given an explicit size via `geometry`, to keep the window from growing and shrinking when the text widget grows or shrinks

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
font = Font(family="Courier", size=10)

def zoom(size):
    font.configure(size=size)

zoom_scale = tk.Scale(root, orient='vertical', from_=1, to=500)
zoom_scale.config(command=zoom)
text = tk.Text(root, font=font)

zoom_scale.pack(fill='y', side='right')
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

zoom_scale.set(10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So, there is no other way to make a zoom except changing size of the font ??

Comment: @Ghantey: correct. That is the only way. Changing the font only changes it in the window. When you save the data, font information isn't saved with the data.

Comment: I followed your suggestion made a working code. I did using tags however I could not add tag when there is no any text in text widget. So, how can I add tag if there is no text in text widget. Here is my code I have written for zooming in and out https://pastebin.com/SujRLUig

Comment: @Ghantey: you don't need to use tags. Just configure the font for the widget. To answer your question, you can't add tags when the text widget is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bryan! can you please also mention zooming text by scrolling with `ctrl` key down? that would be super helpful! :) I'm trying to create a simple text editor, and since most of the text editors have this feature where you ctrl + scroll to zoom in and out, i would like to know how can i add a similar feature to my simple application.